# POST_ not inserting into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert

html page:

```
<input size="100" value="Error Message" name="error" id="error"></td>
```

insert.php:

```
$error=$_POST['$error'];

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(a, z, error, y, z)
      VALUES('$a','$z','$error','$y','$x')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

However the SQL results are:

```
# mysql db_db -e "select * from tickets;"
+---+---+-----------+---------+--------------+
| a | z | error     | y       | x            |
+---+---+-----------+---------+--------------+
| a | z |           | y       | x            |
+---+---+-----------+---------+--------------+
```

What am I missing here? 
Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: You're not [escaping any of your SQL](http://bobby-tables.com/php), using the antiquated and dangerous `mysql_query`, and you haven't used any code-formatting (indent with four spaces), so there's a lot of things missing here.

Comment: As a reference, considering using `$error = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['error']);` instead of what you're doing. It's **much** more secure.

Comment: @Peter Gluck The single quotes are inside the double quotes, so they don't prevent substitution.

Comment: @David, thanks for the edit - I was doing it at the same time apparently.

Comment: @David, thanks for the assistance. I used your example. Obvious newbie question so thanks for being polite ;)

Comment: Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), **it's much more secure** than `mysql_*` functions. Plus, the use of `mysql_*` functions are discouraged.

Comment: This is a quick thing that will only be used on an internal network. Security isn't my immediate concern.

Comment: @cbcp [Have a look at this slide](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies). PDO should still be used, even in an internal network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_POST['$error'];` should be `$_POST['error'];`. You had an extra `$` character in there.

Answer (score -3):

Try this :

```
include (your_db_connection.php);

$a = $_POST['a'];
$z = $_POST['z'];
$error = $_POST['error'];
$y = $_POST['y'];

$query = "INSERT INTO your_table_name(a,z,error,y) VALUES('$a', '$z', '$error', '$y')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "Insert record success.";
```

If I see your code, you have a duplicate column. See in column "z".

Comment: If you take $_POST values and use them directly in a MySQL query without escaping, then [you will get your database hacked](http://bobby-tables.com/). You must use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Comment: I mean, before this function code I thought this will have an input form right.

Comment: X-men learn about `PDO` and `prepared statements`. Your code is open to vulnerabilities.

Comment: Bad code! `include` is not a function but special language construct. Do not put parenthesis there. `include` expects string as argument, you provided constant. User provided data should never be passed directly to SQL query for security reasons. Don't use `mysql`. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: From [the documentation](http://php.net/include): `Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument.` But they are not forbidden. So `include('your_db_connection.php');` would be valid code (with quotes around the filename), as confirmed by the many examples and code samples on the documentation page.

Comment: @Jocelyn that's correct, I know docs. Yet the less mess in the code the better: it's not a function/method - do not put parentheses just to mark that (even if you can).